# Filter with a predicate that takes more than one argument

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I have a list of items that need to be filtered based on a predicate function. The predicate function requires more than one argument to successfully return a result.

Here is my function type declaration, for the function that needs to return the filtered list:

`myFilter :: Int -> [[String]] -> [String] -> [[String]]`

`[[String]]` is the list that needs to be filtered, and is a list of names of people. A name of a person is represented as follows `["FirstName", "MiddleName", "LastName"]`.

`[String]` is the name of an individual, for example `["Bob", "Jane", "Alice"]`.

What I need is to **filter out all names that do not have at least Int number of same names as the individual name**.

For example, if I were to call

`myFilter 2 [["a", "b", "c"],["d", "e", "f"]] ["a", "f", "b"]`

I would get

`[["a", "b", "c"]]` because `["d", "e", "f"]` does not have at least 2 names in common with `["a", "f", "b"]`.

I plan to use this as part of a larger program that allows a user to manage a list of people. One of the functions of this program will be searching by name, returning a list of all people that have name matches based on a user entered integer parameter.

I know of the `filter` function, but it seems like the predicate function should only ever be of the type `p :: Bool`. As you can see my predicate is more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the arguments around a bit:

```
myFilter :: Int -> [String] -> [[String]] -> [[String]]
```

If I understand the question correctly, you want to filter a `[[String]]` and return a `[[String]]`. That fits well with `filter`, which has the type:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Concretely, in this case, `a` is `[String]`, so now you need a function with the type `[String] -> Bool`.

You do, however, need more data than that: the number of matches, and the names to search for, so write a function that also takes these arguments:

```
pred :: Int -> [String] -> [String] -> Bool
```

You can now *partially apply* `pred` with the values you want to search for, e.g. `(pred 2 ["a", "f", "b"])`. That function will have the type `[String] -> Bool`, which matches the requirement of `filter`.

In other words, you should be able to write something like this:

```
myFilter i target names = filter (pred i target) names
```

You can, if you want to, define `pred` inside the `myFilter` function using the `where` keyword, or using `let..in` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may do as follows;

```
myFilter :: Int -> [[String]] -> [String] -> [[String]]
myFilter n ass bs = filter (\as -> n <= length (filter (True ==) ((==) <$> as <*> bs))) ass

*Main> myFilter 2 [["a", "b", "c"],["d", "e", "f"]] ["a", "f", "b"]
[["a","b","c"]]
```

So the `as` is each item of `[[String]]` list.

`(==) <$> as <*> bs)` part works like; `(==) <$> as` would convert `as` into an applicative list functor like `[(=="a"), (=="b"), (=="c")]` and then we apply each function in the applicative to every item of `bs` like `[(=="a"), (=="b"), (=="c")] <*> ["a", "f", "b"]` which results `[True,False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False]` and we filter True values and check the length to see if it's `>= n`.

I hope it is clear.